# Best way to call a function in a class from an object in that class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Okay sorry if this is a silly question. Lets say I have a class, and i want to call a function from that class using an object inside that class to change something within the class. For example:

```
class Foo;
class Bar{
public:
    Bar(Foo *parent): parent(parent) {}
    void barClickEvent(){
        parent->changeSomething(10);
    }
private:
    Foo * parent;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo():bar(this), something(5) {}
    void changeSomething(int x){something = x;}
private:
    Bar bar;
    int something;
};
```

I create an object of type Foo (which automatically creates an object of type Bar). In order to all Bar to access the functions in Foo, I pass a pointer to Bar  pointing to Foo(its parent). Is this the most efficient way of doing this?

The reason I ask this, is because I am implementing something similar to this for the GUI of some software, for example I may click a button in a sidebar, which, in turn, changes the colour of the parent (the main window). In this instance it may not be too bad, but what about when I want to change the entire theme of a UI, and need to call functions in many objects from many parents. I would need alot of pointers, and it could get a bit messy.

Any suggestions on the best way to go about a problem such as this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate way to do this is using [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The idea is to pass a *functional object* to the source of the event. This will ensure that you will be able to set any action for the event without the source of the event knowing what exactly it is.

The easiest way to implement this in C++ is using `std::function` class. For example:

```
#include <functional>

class Bar {
public:
    using OnClicked = std::function<void(int)>;

    void onClicked(OnClicked callback) {
        m_OnClicked = std::move(callback);
    }
    void barClickEvent() {
        if (m_OnClicked)
            m_OnClicked(10);
    }
private:
    OnClicked m_OnClicked;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : something(5) {
        bar.onClicked([this](int value) {
            changeSomething(value);
        });
    }
    void changeSomething(int x){something = x;}
private:
    Bar bar;
    int something;
};
```

As you can see, `Bar` knows nothing about `Foo` which ensures [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) of your components, and now you can have each instance of `Bar` do a completely different thing when event occurs.